# Convert date to remaining time using momentjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, momentjs

In one of the App I am getting date as following formate.
**Mon Aug 18 23:59:59 IST 2014**
Below is ng-repeat for angular js

```
Offer ends:  {{msg.endTime}}
```

Which render as app receive date in this format.
**Offer ends: Mon Aug 18 23:59:59 IST 2014**

I want to show remaining time instead of Date/Time.
Like Offers ends in 2days 40 minutes 10 seconds

Which is simple way to achieve with and without worry about TIMEZone

I am planning to use momentjs with format `moment().format("ddd MMM HH:mm:SS")`

Demo app https://flipkartoffers.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: You should try moment's calendar() method, which automagically does the "in 2 days" and so on.

Comment: Have you checked the answers we provided? If one of them fits, please accept it or share your own solution if you found one. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can create your own filter for that pourpose ...

```
yourOwnApp.filter('datetimeToNow', function() {
  return function(input) {
    if(!input) return;

    return moment(input).fromNow();
  };
});
```

... subsequently just call it from within your ngRepeat:

```
Offer ends:  {{msg.endTime | datetimeToNow}}
```

Cheers,
Luca

Comment: Thanks your hint helped.

Answer (score 4):

It is very easy to achieve using moment and angular-moment. You can use the `am-time-ago` directive. https://github.com/urish/angular-moment

```
<span am-time-ago="message.time"></span>
<span am-time-ago="message.time" am-preprocess="unix"></span>
```

`am-time-ago` works for both 'negative' time (past) and 'positive' time (future)

Comment: I have updated the code but time says 13 years ago.
https://flipkartoffers.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: Will have a look at it once on my computer (smartphone now)

Comment: I am using this https://github.com/urish/angular-moment directive. do you know how to show a full date after some time?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed using [Luca's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2816883/luca-anceschi) answer , and changed formate of the date as below.
Removed the IST 
**Mon Aug 18 23:59:59 2014**

```
<span>Ends {{msg.endTime | formatTime}}</span>
```

-

```
myApp.filter('formatTime', function() {
          return function(text) {
            var m = moment(text , 'ddd MMM DD HH:mm:ss YYYY');
            return m.fromNow();
        }
      })
```

Comment: @apairet accepted answer which helped to find the solution.